# Get all APIs from Microsoft.ApiManagement/service together with TAGS by REST API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rest-api

I'm tring to find a way how to get APIs stored on Azure in Microsoft.ApiManagement/service
I have tried different endpoints but none gave mi API with tags. Is there a way to do so?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**Below are the PowerShell cmdlets for getting the list of APIs registered in an APIM Instance along with their individual API tags**:

```
$ResourceGroupName = "resource_group_name"
$APImg = "APIM_Instance_Name"
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServiceName $APImg
$Apis = Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext
foreach($Api in $Apis){
    $ApiId = $Api.ApiId
    $ApiName = $Api.Name
    $tags = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/tags -ResourceName "$APImg/$ApiId" -ApiVersion 2018-01-01).Name
    Write-Host "Tags of" $ApiName : $tags
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

**To get the list of APIs along with their tags using the REST API, below is the syntax**:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apisByTags?api-version=2021-08-01
```

Thanks to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/api/list-by-tags?tabs=HTTP) as they provided the sample response how it lists the APIs along with their tags for the above cmdlet:

[image]

Refer to the [Azure API Management Rest APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/) for more information.